# Running python script in Task Scheduler

Tags: python-3.x, taskmanager

My inputs into the actions tab are:

```
program/script: Powershell.exe  
add arguments: "lamps_h.py"  
start in: c:\selenium
```

It says "running" but nothing happens. It is a python script that I usually run in the shell terminal.

I have been learning coding for about 3 months so please forgive my ignorance.
Also, this is my first post, so if I missing some etiquette rule, please let me know.

Comment: Are you sure it's not ending quickly?

Comment: At a CMD prompt, if I use `powershell test.py`, I get a red stderr message. If I use the fullpath to `test.py` and pass it to `powershell`, then it works. Powershell with my limited past experience does not inherit current directory.

Comment: If `lamps_h.py` is in `c:\folder 1`, then you may need to use `powershell "c:\folder 1\lamps_h.py"` at a CMD prompt. Similarly, try `"c:\folder 1\lamps_h.py"` for your `add arguments` value.

Comment: @michael_heath - I tried both, did not work but says running... I am thinking maybe i need to make a path directly to power shell but i cant find it...

Comment: Powershell should be in your path variable so I doubt you need it. In CMD, type `set ps` to see value of `PSModulePath`. Type `set path` to see value of path. Or see all variables and values by just typing `set`. On my system, powershell is in `C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0`.

Answer (score 3):

To run Python programs in Task Manager on Windows:
In "Programs/Script" input path to python.exe
In "Add Arguments"input script file name
In "Additional Information" input path to location where file is saved

For example:

Path to Python:
C:\Users\your_user_name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Python.exe

Script name
./script.py

Path to location where script is saved:
C:/foldername/